# Is the Image of a Simplicial Complex under a Simplicial Map again a Simplicial Complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I think this is trivially true, but just wanted confirmation. A simple yes or no would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, though it may be degenerate.